# How do I create symbolic link programatically using C# and .Net core on a linux platform

Tags: c#, .net, linux, asp.net-core, symlink

I have a folder with some file inside of it

I need to move those files and create a symlink instead.
As a cross-platform, this will be run on linux and maybe in windows in the future

- How to create Symlink on linux using C#/.Net core?
- How to know if a file is a real file or a symlink using C#/.Net core?

Environment: **.net core 3.1**
target platform: centos 7
develop platform: win10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
File.CreateSymbolicLink(path, target )
```

path is the destination of the link and target is the path the symbolic Link points to.